# Search for permutation of characters of a substring in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, permutation

I am trying to extract the occurrences of a string and of all the permutations of its characters from a line of text.

For example, I need to extract the string `t = 'ABC'` and all its permutations: 'ABC', 'CAB', 'BCA', 'BAC', 'CBA', from the following string s:

```
s = 'ABCXABCXXACXXBACXXBCA'
```

The results is: `ABC`, `ABC`, `BAC`, `BCA`

The string `t` should be of any length and can contain any characters in `[A-Z]`, `[a-z]` and `[0-9]`

Is there a way to obtain the result by using regular expressions in Python?

I know I could just build a list of all the permutations and then make a separate search for all the items in the list, but I was wondering whether regular expressions can provide the results in a more compact and faster way.

Comment: I don't think regular expression can solve this problem. You probably need to use a sliding window algorithm to find with worst case O(n*a), where n is the length of the string, and a is the size of the alphabet (a = 26 + 26 + 10 = 62 in your case)

Comment: Can string t contain repeating characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me sketch an algorithm to solve the problem. It is not a problem to be solved with regex.

This solution maintains a sliding window, and checks the frequency of characters in the window with that of `t`.

Below is the pseudocode of the algorithm:

```
function searchPermutation(inpStr, t):
    // You may want to check t against the regex ^[A-Za-z0-9]+$ here

    // Do a frequency counting of character in t
    // For example, t = 'aABBCCC'
    // Then freq = { 'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'a': 1 }
    freq = frequency(t)

    // Create an empty dict
    window = {}
    // Number of characters in window
    count = 0
    // List of matches
    result = []

    for (i = 0; i < inpStr.length; i++):
        // If the current character is a character in t
        if inpStr[i] in freq:
            // Add the character at current position
            window[inpStr[i]]++

            // If number of character in window is equal to length of t
            if count == t.length:
                // Remove the character at the end of the window
                window[inpStr[i - t.length]]--
                // The count is kept the same here
            else: // Otherwise, increase the count
                count++

            // If all frequencies in window is the same as freq
            if count == t.length and window == freq:
                // Add to the result a match at (i - t.length + 1, i + 1)
                // We can retrieve the string later with substring
                result.append((i - t.length + 1, i + 1))

                // Reset the window and count (prevent overlapping match)
                // Remove the 2 line below if you want to include overlapping match
                window = {}
                count = 0
        else: // If current character not in t
            // Reset the window and count
            window = {}
            count = 0

    return result
```

This should solve the general problem for any `t`.

Comment: Thanks. After several experiments with regex, I agree the best way is to use a sliding window.

Comment: @cygnusxr1: If there is any bug (e.g. off by 1) in the algorithm above, feel free to comment. I didn't write any actual code to test this, but the idea should be correct.

Comment: (On retrospect, `window == freq` check is expensive. We can keep a map of (char to list of index) to figure out the last index to jump to, as we check that the added character doesn't go over the limit in every step of the loop)

Answer (score 2):

A regex solution:

```
([ABC])(?!\1)([ABC])(?!\1)(?!\2)[ABC]
```